# In opencpu, how to run R source file from gist?

Tags: r, opencpu

I'm trying to execute the R file from gist. But I got this error: `File not found: /tmp/ocpu-www-data/gist_library/ocpu_gist_zhangway_7308452/til.R -X post`

My R source file is publicly [here](https://gist.github.com/zhangway/7308452).

After I typed the HTTP request `https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/gist/zhangway/7308452/til.R -X POST` on the address bar, I got the above error.

However, after I typed `https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/gist/zhangway/7308452/til.R`, the browser can display the source code correctly.

Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up a couple of things. The `-X POST` parameter is for using `curl`:

```
curl -X POST https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/gist/zhangway/7308452/til.R
```

If you don't have curl, try using the [API browser tool](http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/test/) to do the same POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `source_gist` from the `devtools` package

```
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/zhangway/7308452/raw/cd7c333f4b9a7ba09525d47e6e0a4a2f7acccda7/til.R")

[1] "https://gist.github.com/zhangway/7308452/raw/cd7c333f4b9a7ba09525d47e6e0a4a2f7acccda7/til.R"
SHA-1 hash of file is a1d8ff5726f836481bec69a27ae0ae777ac30213
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```